# How can I create a vector in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a small issue where I need to create a vector in `EXCEL VBA`.

I have the following scenario

```
str=Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$12")

Vector= str
```

For example if the cell in `C12` is 11 I want the following output:

```
Vector= "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"
```

Comment: If you have an answer, please submit it as such: as an *answer* (via the button at end of the page). Don't append it to the *question*. If it was another answer to your question that helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark to its left.

Comment: Well if I got less then 10 reputation I cant answer my own question within 8 hours? I posted the answer above to help the comunity, instead I get a thumb down which lowers my reputation...

Comment: I appreciate that you want to help others. With that mindset, I am sure you will soon have enough reputation to be able to do things the right way. Thanks for being patient! (For the record, I didn't downvote.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NUMBERS**

```
  Sub test()
    Dim str As String
    str = Join(Application.Transpose(Evaluate("ROW(A1:A" & Range("C12").Value2 & ")")), " ")
    Debug.Print str
  End Sub
```

**LETTERS**

```
Sub test2()
    Dim str As String, varr, lCnt As Long
    varr = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("64 + ROW(A1:A" & Range("C12").Value2 & ")"))
    For lCnt = LBound(varr, 1) To UBound(varr, 1)
        str = str & " " & Chr(CLng(varr(lCnt)))
    Next lCnt
    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Loop avoider for **LETTERS** :

```
Sub test3()
     Dim str As String
    Const ALPHABET = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
    str = IIf(CLng(Range("C12").Value2) <= 26, _ 
        Mid(ALPHABET, 1, 1 + (2 *CLng(Range("C12").Value2 - 1))), "Error")
    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

You did not specify what happens if the value exceeds the last letter, so I throw an error. Is this what you want?

Comment: @RinorM Your welcome! I hope you eventually solved your problem? In order to help other that might visit this page in the future, could I ask you to (i) either accept an answer, or post your own answer and accept it and (ii) make the title of your question a little more informative, maybe like "generating a delimited string sequence of numbers/letters given its max element" (as you don't really try to create a vector :) ) I have learned a lot from SO by just being an observer, but for that to work it should have accurate question titles and accepted answers. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, do not worry too much about the downvotes, they are part of the game. It wasn't me above, but I see where they are coming from. In general, if you show that you ve tried stuff, your question is clear, and reproducible without too much trouble you should be OK. But then again, dont worry too much :)

Comment: Hi Ioannis, Thank you very much for the advices. I will definitely do that :)!

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Public Function Vector(rIn As Range) As String
    Dim N As Long
    N = rIn(1).Value
    Vector = "1"
    For i = 2 To N
        Vector = Vector & " " & i
    Next i
End Function
```

**EDIT#1:**

To get a **letter** vector, use:

```
Public Function VectorA(rIn As Range) As String
    Dim N As Long
    N = rIn(1).Value
    VectorA = "A"
    For i = 2 To N
        VectorA = VectorA & " " & Chr(64 + i)
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: I managed to fix it now. Thank you for the help. One more question, if The number in cell C12 is 11 but I want the output to be:

*Vector="A B C D E F G H I J K"*  How can I do that?

Comment: Pick a cell and enter: **=Vector(Indata!C12)**

Comment: @RinorM  To get **letter** vector, see my **EDIT#1.**

Comment: I tried it but it comes up an error message that says "duplicate declaration in current scope" and then it highlights "N As Long"

Comment: Make sure you used **VectorA** and did not repeat **Vector**

Comment: I have edited the post above **----Code to use letters instead of numbers-----**

Is that the correct way to write it? Notice that I have both of the codes you helped me with under the same sub.  Thank you

Comment: I have managed to fix it. I post the solution above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**-------SOLUTION-----------**

Here is the solution to the problem above:

```
Dim N As Long
    N = Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$12").Value
    vector = "1"
    For i = 2 To N
        vector = vector & " " & i
    Next i
```

What it does is that it gets a value say 11 from *Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$12").Value* and returns a vector of:

```
vector="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"
```

----Code to use letters instead of numbers-----

> Dim M As Long, vectorA As String
>
> M = Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$13").Value
>
> vectorA = Join(Evaluate("transpose(char(row(65:" & M + 64 & ")))"))

What it does is that it gets a value say 11 from *Sheets("Indata").Range("$C$13").Value* and returns a vector of:

```
vector="A B C D E F G H I J K"
```